# Genomics: What is the most efficient spatial interval index on (chr: ENUM, pos: INT8RANGE)?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

In genomics, an interval is composed of the chromosome [1-22,x,y] and the position on the chromosome (start, end).
The chromosome can be encoded as an enum with 24 different values, the position on the chromosome can be encoded as INT8RANGE.

In order to do efficient range queries and interval joins, I would like to build an index on the columns (chr, pos) but I read that [a GiST index will be relatively ineffective if its first column has only a few distinct values, even if there are many distinct values in additional columns](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/indexes-multicolumn.html).

**What is the best index type on a genomic range in PostgreSQL?**

Answer (score 1):

The warning in the documentation is not correct in my experience.

Or at least its correctness hinges on a rather useless interpretation of "relatively".  Relative to what?  Using a different index type which doesn't support the operations you need to support?  Indexing a different data set, which is not the data set you need to index?

You could swap the order of the columns in the index, but I doubt that would be an improvement, either.  It would probably depend on how wide the ranges typically are, so you would have try it out on your actual data set, not just some naive random number generated data.  I wouldn't even both testing this until you see that you have a problem with the more intuitive index usage.

I would go with the index you indicated, and then try to solve performance problems if/when they have arisen and you have evidence of what the problem is.